# How can I add a click for pageAction?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

First extension—please be kind.

My objective is to offer an option when a user visits pages from a particular domain to offer an option to launch another page which uses part of the visited page's domain name as a variable.

This code below does what I want but it doesn't offer the action as an option—it just executes.

When a page that matches the domain is visited it adds an icon to the address bar. I want the new page called to loaded only when the user clicks on that icon. If that's not possible, please suggest an alternative.

Thanks!

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

  if (tab.url.indexOf('.foo.com') > -1) {

    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    var myName = tab.url.split(".")[0].slice(7);

    if (myName != "www"){ //ignore main site

    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "http://foo.com/foo.html?t=" + myName});
    }

  }
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to use [`chrome.pageAction.onClicked`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#event-onClicked). For example:

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (tab.url.indexOf('.foo.com') > -1) 
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  var myName = tab.url.split(".")[0].slice(7);
  if (myName != "www") //ignore main site
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "http://foo.com/foo.html?t=" + myName});
});
```

Comment: Oh my. I'm elated while feeling a bit dumb at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Above answer is correct but note that you'll need to have the correct permissions in the manifest for this to work or the `tab.url` will be undefined.

From the docs `The URL the tab is displaying. This property is only present if the extension's manifest includes the "tabs" permission.`

Link - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab