# Chrome extension - page action: defining pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a somehow dummy Chrome extension. I want it to run only in specific pages, so I'm using a Page Action.

Let's say I want the page action to run on the Instagram website, then (accordingly [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)), I would need something like this on my `manifest.json` right?

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Some name",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "description": "Some description",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.instagram.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

while the content script runs only on instagram pages as one would expect, the browser extension is not clickable (gray look, and when I click most options are not clickable).

this makes impossible to act upon extension button click. In my `background.js` I have:

```
function click(tab) {
  console.log('click from ' + tab);
}

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(click);
```

that never gets called.

So, what's wrong that makes impossible to act upon extension click on some pages?

> Note: I saw this question/answer, but couldn't find the problem/solution [How can I add a click for pageAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711369/how-can-i-add-a-click-for-pageaction)

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) has a link to [sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:pageaction).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call [`pageAction.show`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show) in order for your pageAction button to be enabled (clickable).

The [`pageAction` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#ui) says (emphasis mine):

> You make a page action appear and be grayed out using the [`pageAction.show`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show) and [`pageAction.hide`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-hide) methods, respectively. **By default, a page action appears grayed out.** When you show it, you specify the tab in which the icon should appear. The icon remains visible until the tab is closed or starts displaying a different URL (because the user clicks a link, for example).

### With a *manifest.json* `content_scripts` entry

Because you already have a content script that runs on the page you desire to have this function on, probably the easiest way to do this is to have your content script [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to your background script telling it to `show` the page-action button for that tab.

Your content script could look something like:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: showPageAction});
```

Your background script could look something like:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(typeof message === 'object' && message.type === 'showPageAction') {
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }
});
```

### Without a *manifest.json* `content_scripts` entry

If you did not have a content script, you would probably want to use a [`webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) listener, or [`tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) listener, to listen for a change in the tab's URL in order to determine that the page-action button should be shown.  Obviously, the trigger for calling `pageAction.show()` does not have to be the URL which is currently displayed in the tab, but that is the most common.

Comment: The example I used actually had the`showPageAction`, but I deleted because the example had too much "trash" that I wouldn't need. I guess I deleted too much :) Do you know the reasoning not to have the button automatically not grayed on pages you already choose to run the extension?

Comment: @pedrorijo91, How is it supposed to know that "you already choose to run the extension"? It's not reasonable for it to just assume that because you are injecting a content script, that the pageAction button should be active. It would be reasonable for it to have a setting in *manifest.json* to tell it that is the case, but there's no such setting.